# Financial Support

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

If I do have a sponsorship for continuing my masters degree, will that increase my chances of getting accepted, or is money irrelevant in admissions decisions? I am considering computer science or computational engineering graduate studies in the United States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admissions in the US are not necessarily need-blind at either the undergraduate or graduate levels, **[even if the university claims it is](http://blog.georgetownvoice.com/2013/10/23/gw-lied-about-having-need-blind-admissions-for-years/)!**

Especially at the graduate level, it is more or less accepted that ability to "self-fund" one's education, through fellowships and scholarships, or other arrangements, can be considered as a factor in admissions processes.

Comment: So if I am financially sponsored I have a better chance of getting an acceptance, right?!